Connecting to aurora postgresql using R2DBC via IAM authentication
I am working on a SpringBoot Webflux project. I am trying to connect to Aurora Postgres using IAM authentication. I want to use R2DBC for database interaction but, there are no documents available for the same that explains the process or any sample code to integrate the R2DBC with IAM.
Any leads or workaround for this?
